# Linux kernel: sequence of events/paths before process coredump happens

Tags: linux, process, kernel, coredump, segmentation-fault

When there is a segmentation fault and a process coredump is generated what are the sequence of events happening in kernel and user space (w.r.t Linux) ?

Linux does support a sigsegv handler.
How does the signal handler gets called and on return a coredump is generated ?

I'm looking for sequence of events and any pointers to linux kernel function names (w.r.t any latest kernel).
I will figure the rest from the function names, I'do understand can make out the rest from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a SIGSEGV is generated, the kernel checks if there is a handler for it.  If there is, it will call it, just like any other signal.  If there is a handler, no core will be generated.  This happens in get_signal_to_deliver: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/signal.c#n2192

If it gets to the default action for SIGSEGV, it will generate a coredump and exit.  The coredump is generated by do_coredump in fs/coredump.c: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/coredump.c#n485